# How to remove save_as icon in Altair plots

Tags: python, altair

By default Altair charts are displayed with a menu icon in the upper right, represented by a circular icon with three dots: [image]

How can I display a chart without this menu?

Here is a short example:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
source = data.cars()

alt.Chart(data.cars.url).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower:Q',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
    color='Origin:N',
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as the "actions" menu, and it is not a property of the chart, but of the renderer. Its presence and appearance can be controlled via [embed options](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed#options) in the renderer settings.

Here is an example of setting the `actions` option to False, which will hide the menu:

```python
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

alt.renderers.set_embed_options(actions=False)

source = data.cars()

alt.Chart(data.cars.url).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower:Q',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
    color='Origin:N',
)
```

[image]

No more actions menu!

Comment: This doesn't work outside Jupyter, for instance in Streamlit.

Comment: Echoing the comment above about this not working in Streamlit.

Comment: Streamlit has its own non-standard Vega rendering frontend. I’d suggest inquiring with streamlit-specific help forums regarding how to configure it.